# Enable/disable CupertinoDialogAction depending on CupertinoTextField is empty or not

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

I want to set CupertinoDialogAction to enable if CupertinoTextField is not empty else by default it should be disabled, also I have set the "isDefaultAction: false" but it is still clickable.

```
showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
            actions: [
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                onPressed: () => (Navigator.of(context).pop()),
                child: Text("Cancel"),
              ),
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                child: Text("Save"),
                isDefaultAction: false,
              ),
            ],
            title: Text("New Folder"),
            content: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text("Enter a name for this folder"),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 30,
                  child: CupertinoTextField(
                    controller: folderName,
                    placeholder: "Name",
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable a `CupertinoDialogAction`, you need to set the `onPressed` property to `null`. It will look like this:

```
       Bool isEnabled = false;

       @override
       void initState() {
         super.initState();

         folderName.addListener(enableButton); // addListened to your TextEditingController!
       }
```

It will set isEnabled to true.

```
      enableButton()
      {
        if(folderName.text != "")
        {
          setState(() {
            isEnabled = true;
          });
        }                
      }
```

And, then you can use this boolean field.

```
      CupertinoDialogAction(
              onPressed: !isEnabled 
                  ? null
                  : () {
                      // Do what you need!
                      // Save method!
                    },
              child: Text("Save"),
              isDefaultAction: false,
            ),
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the "Save" CupertinoDialogAction remains disabled even after i enter some text in the CupertinoTextField which is not the behavior i expect.

Comment: You can try to add a listener to your TextEditingController.

Comment: I edited the answer. You can check again.

Comment: It is still not working ,the Save DialogAction remains disabled ,may be the TextController doesn't get the changes in TextField, and the DEBUG CONSOLE shows exception   "The method 'call' was called on null.",  "Receiver: null
",  "Tried calling: call()
"

Comment: The error might be in another place where you call the call() method. Can you share that part of your code too?

Comment: there is no method name "call()"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225585/discussion-between-neeleshwar-kumar-and-akif).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a stateful widget that builds the list of actions and returns `CupertinoAlertDialog` with those actions. This widget should contain some state that indicates if the save action should be enabled or not. If it should not be enabled, put null into the `onPressed` handler.
2. Write some handler that uses `setState` to set this enabled/disabled state depending on what the user is doing.
3. Return your stateful widget from the `showDialog` builder